# How to add transition effect for css background-color change

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here is my css code:

```css
#btn {background-color:red; color:blue;}
#btn:hover {background-color:green;}
```

How can I add transition on hover event. I have no idea hiw transitions work. A little descriptive answer would be appereciated.

Comment: Any simple searchengine search would have found you the knowledge you need. This question should be closed due to the obvious lazyness of its author.

Comment: Oh thanks dear. Perhaps you are too lazy to learn proper grammar

Comment: "hiw transitions work" - "would be appereciated". You do know the saying with the glass house? Come back when your brain has left the child phase.

Comment: Bye the way i am 9 yrs only... :p

Answer (score 1):

Use [`transition: background-color transition-duration timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) on normal state.

```
#btn {
  background-color: #288FB4;
  transition: background-color 1s ease; /* Add */
}
#btn:hover {
  background-color: #5A67A6;
}
```

**Output:**

```css
#btn {
  background-color: #288FB4;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: background-color 1s ease; /* Add */
}
#btn:hover {
  background-color: #5A67A6;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">Hover me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Transition property you need to use.

```
#btn {
  background-color: #999;
  transition: background-color 1s ease; /* ease, ease-in, ease-in-out*/
}
#btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcf5ec88/)